# In Qt, I set setChecked(false) for the button, but it failed and isChecked remained true?

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following piece of code, it seems a little long, but it's very simple, and now I have a problem.
I created some buttons in each page of the ToolBox, and put these buttons into a Group for management, and put these groups into a QList for management. When I clicked the button on the first page, signals and slots were triggered. and set the button clicked to the selected state (find and setChecked(true)).
When I switch pages, I want the status of all the buttons on the previous page to reset, that is, to be left unchecked.
I then get the group of all the buttons on the previous page and set all of them to setChecked(false), but it doesn't work and remains true in the output of isChecked().

[In first page, clicked one button and setCheck(true)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KxAN.png)

[When I switch to page 2, it should trigger the switch signal for ToolBox, and follow my instructions to set all buttons on page 1 unchecked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OduKJ.png)

[But when I switch to page 1 again, it's still checked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJNTz.png)

in the output window:

```
true
false
```

Can someone help me? I have been troubled by this question for several days, looking forward to your answer!

Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QToolBox>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QButtonGroup>

class Widget:public QWidget {
public:
    Widget(QWidget* parent = nullptr):QWidget(parent) {
        this->resize(300, 300);
        createToolBox();
    }
    ~Widget() {}
    void createToolBox() {
        //Create the buttons for the first page, and put all the buttons in a group to manage, and put the group in the QList to manage
        ls.push_back(btnGroup_1 = new QButtonGroup);
        btnGroup_1->setExclusive(true);

        //Connect signals and slots, to achieve click button
        connect(btnGroup_1, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this, &Widget::onTriggered_btnGroup_1);

        //Create a GridLayout and place the two buttons
        QGridLayout* gird_1 = new QGridLayout;
        gird_1->addWidget(createToolButton("toolButton_a1",1), 0, 0);
        gird_1->addWidget(createToolButton("toolButton_a2",1), 1, 0);

        //Finally create a widget and set layout above.
        QWidget* widget_1 = new QWidget;
        widget_1->setLayout(gird_1);

        //----------------------------------
        //Do exactly the same as above, to create the second page content.
        ls.push_back(btnGroup_2 = new QButtonGroup);
        btnGroup_2->setExclusive(true);

        connect(btnGroup_2, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this, &Widget::onTriggered_btnGroup_2);

        QGridLayout* gird_2 = new QGridLayout;
        gird_2->addWidget(createToolButton("toolButton_b1",2), 0, 0);
        gird_2->addWidget(createToolButton("toolButton_b2",2), 1, 0);

        QWidget* widget_2 = new QWidget;
        widget_2->setLayout(gird_2);


        //--------------------------------
        // Create a QToolBox and add the two pages.
        toolBox = new QToolBox(this);
        toolBox->setMinimumWidth(200);
        toolBox->setMaximumWidth(200);
        toolBox->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
        toolBox->addItem(widget_1, "widget_1");
        toolBox->addItem(widget_2, "widget_2");

        //Most important of all. 
        //When I switch pages I need to reset all the buttons on the previous page to unselected
        connect(toolBox, &QToolBox::currentChanged, this, [=](int value) {
            //record the previous page index. I am sure this value is right.
            preToolBoxIndex = curToolBoxIndex;
            curToolBoxIndex = value;

            //to get the previous page's all buttons;
            QList<QAbstractButton*> btns = ls[preToolBoxIndex]->buttons();
            for (auto& x : btns) {
                x->setChecked(false);
                //Most confusion is that if the state of x is true, even if setChecked(false) is done, it still prints true in this output.
                qInfo() << x->isChecked();
            }
        });
    }
    //to create toolbutton
    QWidget* createToolButton(const QString& text,int type) {
        QToolButton* btn = new QToolButton;
        btn->setObjectName("function_tbtn");
        btn->resize(48, 48);
        btn->setCheckable(true);
        btn->setChecked(false);

        if (type == 1) {
            btnGroup_1->addButton(btn,type);
        }
        else if (type == 2) {
            btnGroup_2->addButton(btn, type);
        }

        QGridLayout* grid = new QGridLayout;
        grid->addWidget(btn, 0, 0, Qt::AlignHCenter);
        QLabel* textlab = new QLabel(text);
        textlab->setObjectName("textLab");
        grid->addWidget(textlab, 1, 0, Qt::AlignHCenter);

        QWidget* wid = new QWidget;
        wid->setLayout(grid);

        return wid;
    }
public slots:
    void onTriggered_btnGroup_1(QAbstractButton* btn) {
        //choice the clicked button and setChecked(true).
        QList<QAbstractButton*> btns = btnGroup_1->buttons();
        for (auto& m_btn : btns) {
            if (m_btn == btn) {
                m_btn->setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    }
    void onTriggered_btnGroup_2(QAbstractButton* btn) {
        QList<QAbstractButton*> btns = btnGroup_2->buttons();
        for (auto& m_btn : btns) {
            if (m_btn == btn) {
                m_btn->setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    }
private:
    QButtonGroup* btnGroup_1 = nullptr;
    QButtonGroup* btnGroup_2 = nullptr;

    //QList to manager all QButtolGroup
    QList<QButtonGroup*> ls;


    QToolBox* toolBox = nullptr;
    int preToolBoxIndex = 0;
    int curToolBoxIndex = 0;

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I thought that the index of the page before I got it was wrong, but in fact it was not wrong, and the button group I got was really from the previous page, I hoped that all the buttons were unselected when I switched the page, but now it failed, I don't know why it made an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot uncheck a `QAbstractButton` if it belongs to an exclusive group, which is the case in the code provided in your question.

This is the intended behavior and it is documented as I explained in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75379353/20143744).

You can try to change your lambda to remove the `Exclusive` property on your group, then uncheck all buttons, then restore the property. That means something like:

```cpp
btnGroup->setExclusive(false);
for (auto& x : btns) {
    ....
}
btnGroup->setExclusive(true);
```